# Use count as variable name within \foreach

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgffor

I'm trying to build a bar graph using `\foreach`.I'd like to have each bar colored based on a variable defined. (this is part of a broader project, so I can't change how they are defined.)

Using the `\count` macro to have the index value at each iteration, I'd like to use it to choose the correct color of the bar.
But the macro `\n` (which is the index) is taken as is, and not its value.
Hence I get an error about `Undefined color 'color@\n'`.

I've checked by using `typeout` that the value is correct, it's just that it doesn't seem to be a string or something...

Here is a MWE :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,pgffor}

\colorlet{color@1}{green}
\colorlet{color@2}{yellow}
\colorlet{color@3}{orange}
\colorlet{color@4}{red}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xtick={1,...,4},
            x tick style={draw=none},
            xticklabel={1},
            ymin=0,
            every axis plot/.append style={ybar,fill}
        ]
        \foreach \x [count=\n] in {1,3,2,10}{
            \typeout{index is \n}
            \addplot[color=color@\n ] coordinates {(\n,\x)};
            % Here is the error about color@\n undefined.
        }
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\tikz[x=0.75cm,y=0.75cm]
\foreach \x [count=\xi] in {a,...,d}
\foreach \y [count=\yi] in {\x,...,d}
\node [draw, top color=white, bottom color=color@\xi, minimum size=0.666cm]
at (\xi,-\yi) {$\xi,\yi$};
    
\end{document}
```

The second example is working perfectly well and is adapted from the documentation.
I don't see where the error is in the first example.

[image: MWE result]

Could it be an expansion error ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expansion of the optional argument to `\addplot` was definitely quite finicky.  In the end, I use a `listofitems` list to define and expand the colors. See **ADDENDUM** for version without `listofitems`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,pgffor,listofitems}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\readlist\colorlist{green,yellow,orange,red}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xtick={1,...,4},
            x tick style={draw=none},
            xticklabel={1},
            ymin=0,
            every axis plot/.append style={ybar,fill}
        ]
        \readlist\mylist{1,3,2,10}
        \foreachitem \x \in \mylist[]{
            \typeout{index is \xcnt}
            \edef\tmp{color=\colorlist[\xcnt]}
            \expandafter\addplot\expandafter[\tmp] 
               coordinates {(\xcnt,\x)};
        }
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\tikz[x=0.75cm,y=0.75cm]
\foreach \x [count=\xi] in {a,...,d}
\foreach \y [count=\yi] in {\x,...,d}
\node [draw, top color=white, bottom color={\colorlist[\xi]}, minimum size=0.666cm]
at (\xi,-\yi) {$\xi,\yi$};
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**

Version without using `listofitems`.  In both cases, the key is expanding the color before presenting it to the `\addplot`, by way of

```
        \edef\tmp{color=color@\n}
        \expandafter\addplot\expandafter[\tmp] 
           coordinates {(\n,\x)};
```

The MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,pgffor}
\colorlet{color@1}{green}
\colorlet{color@2}{yellow}
\colorlet{color@3}{orange}
\colorlet{color@4}{red}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xtick={1,...,4},
            x tick style={draw=none},
            xticklabel={1},
            ymin=0,
            every axis plot/.append style={ybar,fill}
        ]
        \foreach \x [count=\n] in {1,3,2,10}{
            \typeout{index is \n}
            \edef\tmp{color=color@\n}
            \expandafter\addplot\expandafter[\tmp] 
               coordinates {(\n,\x)};
        }
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\tikz[x=0.75cm,y=0.75cm]
\foreach \x [count=\xi] in {a,...,d}
\foreach \y [count=\yi] in {\x,...,d}
\node [draw, top color=white, bottom color=color@\xi, minimum size=0.666cm]
at (\xi,-\yi) {$\xi,\yi$};
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it however possible to do it without a `listofitems` ? I'd like minimal change to the code...

Comment: @3isenHeim I have provided a version without `listofitems` in the **ADDENDUM** to my answer.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks !